# Explicit Satake isomorphism

Tags: rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms

Consider the group $G=GL(n)$ over a non-Archimedean field and $K$ a maximal compact subgroup. Let $(\pi, V)$ be a smooth admissible irreducible representation of $G$, say spherical. I would like to understand pretty explicitly the Satake isomorphism in this setting.

We know $V^K$ is at most one-dimensional (since the Hecke algebra $H(G//K)$ is commutative, and so is one-dimensional since we assumed sphericality. Letting $v \in V^K$ being a spherical vector in $V$, we therefore have
$$f \cdot v = \int_G f(g) \pi(g) g dg = \lambda_{f, v} v$$
by one-dimensionality. I feel this eigenvalue $\lambda_f$ is one of the keys of understanding the Satake isomorphism.

More precisely, any spherical vector is part of a (subrepresentation of a) spherical principal series, and these are of the form $Ind_P^G(\chi)$ for a certain unramified character $\chi$ of $G$. Call $v_\chi$ such a vector. So we can look more generally at
$$f \in H(G//K) \longmapsto \lambda_{f,\chi}$$
so that, as above, $f \cdot v_\chi = \lambda_{f,\chi} v_\chi$.

All the unramified characters $\chi$ are of the form $diag(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \mapsto |a_1|^{s_1} \cdots |a_n|^{s_n}$ for complex numbers $s_i$. My first question is that I would like to deduce
$$\lambda_{f, \chi} \in \mathbb{C}[X_1^{\pm 1}, \cdots, X_n^{\pm 1}]^W$$
where $X_i = |\varpi|^{s_i}$, $\varpi$ is a uniformizer and $W$ the Weyl group.

My second question is: is the map
$$f \in H(G//K) \longrightarrow \lambda_{f, \chi} \in \mathbb{C}[X_1^{\pm 1}, \cdots, X_n^{\pm 1}]^W$$
the so-called Satake isomorphism (in the spherical case)?

Comment: One needs to shift the character $\chi$ by half the sum of the positive roots before parabolically inducing to get a formula of this type, so that the induced representation is really invariant under the Weyl group.

Comment: @WillSawin Isn't that built into the conventional definition of normalised parabolic induction?

Comment: For a fixed $f$ and varying $\chi$, it is clear that $\lambda_{f, \chi}$ is a function of the variables $X_i = |\varpi|^{s_i}$ but not so obvious that it is a *polynomial* in these and their inverses. That is the key step here.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Sure, it's just not obvious to me whether the notation refers to the normalised parabolic induction or the naive parabolic inductionn.

Comment: https://abel.math.harvard.edu/~gross/preprints/sat.pdf and https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00026-018-0391-3 may be useful for both directions.